# An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Hi I am trying to load data from a csv to sql server. The data types in flat file source external and output are (DT_STR,50). I am converting them to their respective data types in a derived column and trying to send all the wrong fields to an error file. But when I am trying to load. I am getting the following error.

**Error: 0xC0049064 at Data Flow Task, Derived Column [668]: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.
Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, Derived Column [668]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.**

The field on which it is failing is 0.234 I am trying to convert it from (DT_STR,50) to (DT_NUMERIC,7,5). I do not understand why this is failing. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you use the `DataConversion` transformation?

Comment: I've always had more luck converting data types using a script transformation. You would be able to have more freedom to use specific .net casting functions and could even perform necessary data sanitation etc.Not sure what the speed implications of this would be, I would guess it would be slower than using a data conversion or derived column component.

Comment: Can you check the internationalization, SSIS maybe expects a "," instead of a "." as the decimal separator

Comment: @JeffOrris I have the same issue with DataConversion transformation.

Comment: @JonM  Do you have an example? How to do it in a script task?

Comment: Not a script task (inside a control flow) but a script transformation (inside a data flow) You can use either c# or vb to load the source columns into a pre built .net class and then apply simple conditions to test whether the values can be converted and convert them if necessary. You would also be able to sanitize them e.g. removing commas from decimal strings. There are lots of guides out there on this for example: http://sqlage.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/ssis-how-to-use-script-component-as.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SSIS throws some pretty generic errors and there are probably dozens of ways you can encounter this one.

I ran into this when I was unaware that my flat file contained a footer that contained a different set of fields than the normal data rows.

I discovered this after I redirected my error rows to a Multicast and enabled the data viewer on my output which let me see what was failing.

In my case, I could see that I had a footer with a reliable value that I could detect with a Conditional Split to skip it. After that, my numeric cast in the derived column behaved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that at least one of the values in your (DT_STR,50) field cannot fit (DT_NUMERIC,7,5) because it has more that 7 number characters. Enable a Data Viewer on the path that's inputting into the Data Conversion step and you will probably see what I mean (depending on buffer size, you will likely have to sort on the string field in question). If you don't see one that's too long, buffer though until you do and buffer again, at which time the Data Conversion step will fail.

I had this same error thrown while trying to convert an INT that was too big for the NUMERIC length and precision I was casting to.